# Data Hierarchy with Table Views in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have possibly many nested list..For exampel

I have a list and contains some folders, when user tapped it, i show content of the folder in the same tableview.. and this content may has some folders also, can when user tapped it, it also shows the same in the tableview.

but each type of list of the tableview can be different. For example, first folder's list is list of X class, but the second one can be Y class..

I did something but it doesnt work properly in some cases. So I do not know how to solve this kind of nested list.

as scheme,
Folder 1-> (Folder X,Folder Y, Document 1, Document 2)
if user tap folder X

folder X ->  (folder a, folder b)

but  this list (Folder X,Folder Y, Document 1, Document 2) is class of X, like List
this list (folder a, folder b) is class of Y like List

because webservice send me like that..

I know that it is complicated but i hope it is clear.

I am using Xamarin.ios, but doesnt matter for objective-c. I just seek for possible solution. Like a generic list?

Comment: This question is very confusing. What code have you tried?

Comment: Yes I know sorry but its really complex for me.. I created an enum to catch which kind of category user choose. Actually my problem is when user back. Because this time i need to handle previous list. But sometimes it doesnt work.. In this class i wrote 1600 lines code :) so its not possible to share

Comment: In an iOS TableView, I don't see what the problem is with having several cell subclasses, and each of these subclasses can have a different behavior in the table view. This is probably the approach you need to take

Comment: but types of the source (list) are different than each other and when i tapped the back button, previous link is removed and if i go a few steps and going back is problem.. yeah i know its difficult to explain here :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Nested Lists:**

In your view controller keep a list of the "selected objects" (it would behave as a stack). When you select a cell, add that corresponding folder / document / ... object to the `selectedObjects` list/stack. If you go back, remove the last element. When showing objects for the table view, take the last entry in the list/stack and you know "where you are".

A sample use case following your example:

1. `selectedObjects` is empty
2. Tap "Folder 1" in table view
3. Add "Folder 1" to the end of `selectedObjects`
4. Show the sub elements of "Folder 1" being Folder X,Folder Y, Document 1, Document 2
5. Tap "Folder X" in table view
6. Add "Folder X" to the end of `selectedObjects` (the list now has two entries "Folder 1" and "Folder X")
7. Show the sub elements of "Folder X" being folder a, folder b
8. Tap "Back" in table view
9. Remove the last entry from `selectedObjects`, now it contains only "Folder 1"
10. Get the last entry from `selectedObjects` which now is "Folder 1"
11. You have the folder for which to show the sub list

**2. Different Classes:**

If there is no other way, you could create a base class - say - `CellData`. Then for each different class which you get from your webservice, create a subclass - say - `FolderCellData` and `DocumentCellData`. Each of the subclasses holds a reference to the actual instance which you get from the web service. Then you could use lists of `CellData` to hold references to class X and Y.

There will be code which "decides" which of the `CellData` subclasses to use depending on the class from the webservice. These decisions may as well be placed in the rendering (decide which `UITableViewCell` to use?) or in the user input handling (Which cell has been tapped -> which class is it in the list of objects?). So you may as well use a list of `NSObject`s anyway and save you from having to maintain a mirror class hierarchy for the webservices classes.

Comment: thank you very much for your detail answer @RainerSchwarze.. I think that i am going to user your way.. but maybe i will use a generic list. Thank you again